# Google Earth Client: Where are the local placemark icons stored?

Tags: google-earth, arcgis-earth

While working in Google Earth on computer disconnected from the internet, I created a few placemarks, with some of the built-in icons.  I saved the layers to a KML file.  When I opened the KML file, I noticed that all of the icons were href'ed to:

`<href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>`

The curious thing is that the machine was not connected to the Internet.  However, the placemark icons showed up fine, indicating that the file `ylw-pushpin.png` is somewhere on the local machine.  However, a full search of the entire drive turned up no matching files.

The question is driven by work I'm doing attempting to tidy up KML content for use in Esri's ArcGIS Earth.  ArcGIS Earth (when disconnected) does not know how to interpret these icon links and displays a default red X.  If I know where to go on the local workstation to check for the png files, I can script up a solution.  But for now, I'm just perplexed as to where/how they are being loaded.

Comment: Assume you're using Earth Pro, not web or mobile versions?  Not sure, but I think icons and other image files may be included in Earth's cache file, just like the last latest imagery & terrain you loaded is also cached for offline use.

Comment: A simple "search text within files" points to the file `C:\Program Files\Google\Google Earth Pro\client\res\localshapes.rcc`

Comment: @JGH thanks, I was able to use python to extract all the PNG files I needed from there.